# bash dateformat [date]T[time]Z to normal datetime

Tags: bash, datetime, sed

I have a very ugly dateformat in this datatable:

```
adress1@gmail.com othermail@pri.com 2014-03-31T13:24:04Z 555555
adress2@gmail.com othermail2@pri.com 2014-03-31T13:36:19Z 555555
```

I wanted to change the dateformat from this [date]T[time]Z format to normal datetime with:

```
cat file.csv |sed 's/[0-9]T[0-9]/[0-9] [0-9]/g'
```

but it gives back

```
adress1@gmail.com othermail@pri.com 2014-03-3[0-9] [0-9]3:24:04Z 555555
adress2@gmail.com othermail2@pri.com 2014-03-3[0-9] [0-9]3:36:19Z 555555
```

insted of

```
2014-03-31 13:24:04Z
```

Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: When you are working with dates it is always interesting to make use of `date` command. It makes things way easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make use of backreferences:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)T\([0-9]\)/\1 \2/g' file.csv
```

If you know that the date is the third field in your input, you could also use `awk`:

```
awk '{sub("T", " ", $3)}1' file.csv
```

Comment: @TomiMester: Don't forget to _accept_ the answer (click on the large check mark next to it).